# Frequencies in mp3

Tags: c++, mp3, fftw

I`m tried to get information about frequency characteristics of music file in mp3 format.

How to get frequencies from mp3 file with c++? And with what data does the fftw library work?

Comment: Often the easiest approach is to convert the MP3 files to WAV, using existing tooling such as `sox`. WAV is trivial to read from C++.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a two step process, first you need to read the mp3 file into a data-structure of your liking in your C++ program. Most mp3 files are stereo format meaning you will have two arrays/vectors, one for each channel. FFTW works in two steps as well, first you create a plan describing your data, number of FFT points, Inverse/Forward FFT direction etc. In the next step you use this plan and your input data to compute frequency transforms. You can then take the magnitude response of the resulting float/double complex array from FFTW. Link to FFTW tutorial http://www.fftw.org/fftw2_doc/fftw_2.html

Having said that, you do not need to go through these steps manually, there are many open source Music information retrieval libraries that can do this for you, like [Marsyas](https://github.com/marsyas/marsyas). You can also use audio libraries such as [PortAudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) to get audio data and get the results you want by feeding that data to signal processing libraries like [openvsip](https://github.com/openvsip/openvsip) or [LiquidDSP](https://github.com/jgaeddert/liquid-dsp)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I understand correctly the right moment: in mp3 format audiodata is compressed and to get the correct information about frequencies it would be desirable to convert it to eg .wav before use fftw or it does not matter?

Comment: MP3 is lossy data compression scheme which means if you apply FFT directly to the MP3 frames (data part of course) there will be some difference to original frequency spectrum but it should still be pretty close. Converting to Wav format will probably open up more possibilities to process audio data. But as I said earlier unless this is for self-learning or assignment, one should be using an audio library which supports reading MP3